# Moment.JS: fromNow() more accurate

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to display times etc..., and I'm using `moment(OBJECT).fromNow()` for my coding.
It just returns a generalized time like: `1 day ago` instead of `20 hours and 4 minutes ago` as an example.

I really dug through the documentation but I found nothing that would display `.fromNow()` more accurately.

Comment: i found this link, hopefully it will help: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/02-fromnow/

Comment: The way the documentation explicitly lists which output you can expect for what kind of time range, I don't think this was made customizable.

Comment: You could use a `duration` and use [`humanize`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/), but I think it uses the same code. In any case, [Moment.js is in legacy maintenance mode](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) and you may want to consider alternatives.